# Using Software Updates, Updates fail each time

Tags: 12.10

Using Software Updates, Updates fail each time, also seems to find a different update each time I use app.... last evening "successfully" inatalled 12.10 upgrade...

```
Preparing to replace libdrm2:amd64 2.4.39-0ubuntu1 (using .../libdrm2_2.4.39 0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdrm2:amd64 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.39-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libdrm2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libdrm2:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.39-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 4):

I just moved the `/usr/share/doc/libdrm2/changelog.Debian.gz` file out of the way and the upgrade worked without problems.

```
....
Setting up libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-18-generic
```